# easiet way to get my changes linked with svn base

Tags: svn

I have a couple of files in my local workspace area. When I run a command `svn status` on these files I am getting against these files. Now I have my changes into these files. I want to get the latest version of these files from the svn repositry and merge my changes into these files. Can someone tell me what is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: SVNBook will help you: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a checkout from the Subversion repository? All you have to do is an *update* and a *commit*.

That will put your changes back on the server.

Comment: Thanks David and bahrep for your suggestions.